# Motor de almacenamiento MySQL (MyISAM a INNODB)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb, myisam

Tengo un hosting en GoDaddy, estuve probando, realice unas pruebas con las transacciones `(begin, rollback, commit)`, las cuales no tenían ningún efecto.
Estuve investigando y me di cuenta que "MyISAM" no permite realizar transacciones, por lo cual supuse que el motor de almacenamiento que tengo en estos momento es ese. También estuve consultando y mirando el CPanel de GoDaddy y no encontre ningún lugar donde pudiera ver el motor de almacenamiento y mucho menos modificarlo. ¿alguien que sepa como realizar este cambio?

Sería de mucha ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes intentar es cambiar el motor de almacenamiento con una sentencia SQL tienes que hacerlo para cada tabla que requieras:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

para establecerla como default si tu plan es shared la única opción es revisarlo con tu proveedor para ver si ellos lo pueden cambiar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me a servido

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes acceso a la consola mysql ejecuta:

```
 show engines;
```

Pulsa intro y verás el motor que utiliza tu base de datos por defecto y también puedes ver si InnoDB está disponible o no.

Lamentablemente desconozco los servidores de GoDaddy, pero sería muy interesante conocer la versión de mysql que estás usando y saber si tienes acceso root al bash del sistema (en el caso de que tengas un Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Usando el comando:

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

Puedes obtener el siguiente resultado y verificar si tienes acceso al motor `INNODB` disponible en tu gestor de bases de datos

```
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

> Y observar en la columna que dice `Support`, como puedes verificar a mi
>   me sale la leyenda **Defualt** por que a parte de que si lo soporta
>   viene por defecto

Puedes indicar por ejemplo al momento de crear tu tabla, el motor con el que debe trabajar de este modo, como puedes observar la coloque al final de la instrucción y ya con eso te debería respetar que deseas trabajar con `INNODB`:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
status_user TINYINT(1) NOT NULL)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**¿Si ya tengo mis tablas creadas que puedo hacer?**

Con el comando `ALTER` para modificar el `ENGINE` que tenga, de este modo

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Con el comando anterior, lograremos alterar el `ENGINE` original y trasladarlo por ejemplo de `MyISAM` a `INNODB`

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había fijado que cuando iba a crear la base de datos me permitía seleccionar un motor de almacenamiento.

Comment: de nada @Ochoa15 despero te haya servido la respuesta para avanzar y continuar tu proyecto